# TypeScript `extend` produces ESLint error when extending a generic

Tags: typescript, eslint

I have a load of models that have some meta data appended, so I created a generic type to append them to the models when they're present:

```
type WithMeta<T> = T extends Meta;
```

Although this produces the following error: `Parsing error: '?' expected.`

ESLint isn't telling me which rule is triggering this, so hoping someone here knows the answer? Thanks

Comment: type WithMeta<T extends Meta> should work

Comment: @MarekW is there a way I can do this with an empty body? I'm basically looking to just combine a class and interface, something like: `WithMeta = {...T, ...Meta}`

Comment: Sadly you can not spread a class, you would have to write a function which returns all the fields you want to add to the object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue with `&`:

```
interface Meta {
  createdAt: string;
  updatedAt: string;
}

type WithMeta<T> = T & Meta;
```

Comment: This worked for me too. Is there a reason for this though? I thought using `&` was simple syntax sugar.